# WPF - Custom Pie Menu - MenuItem Image

Tags: c#, wpf, menu

Does anybody can help me, to add a image to each MenuItem of this tutorial:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/522343/A-Pie-Menu-for-WPF

I have no idea, how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
</MyNamespace:PieMenu.BitmapEffect>
  <Image Source="Items\1.png" Width="50" Height="50"/>
  <Image Source="Items\2.png" Width="50" Height="50"/>
  <Image Source="Items\3.png" Width="50" Height="50"/>
  <Image Source="Items\4.png" Width="50" Height="50"/>
  <Image Source="Items\5.png" Width="50" Height="50"/>
</MyNamespace:PieMenu>
```

Comment: No ... unfortunately this is not working. Compiler says, that "Image" is not supported by the "BitmapEffect"property.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I ended up playing with the header property of the PieMenuItem. Something like this will work.

```
    if (menu_item.Header as FrameworkElement != null)
    {
        FrameworkElement header = (FrameworkElement)menu_item.Header;

        // Create the visual brush based on the UserControl
        VisualBrush headerVisualBrush = new VisualBrush(header);
        headerVisualBrush.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;

        // Draw using the visual brush in the rect
        double contentSize = distance / 2;
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(headerVisualBrush, null, new Rect(center.X - contentSize / 2.0, center.Y - contentSize / 2.0, contentSize, contentSize));
  }
  else if (menu_item.Header as String != null)
  {

  }
```